# Validating age using a function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

so i'm having some issues using a function in SQL where i calculate the age given a certain date. The thing is that i need to validate with the current date and the date of birth if it's already the year or not.

For example the date i have in a register is 1994-11-15 and when consulting the information with

`select EmployeeID Num_Emloyee, concat(FirstName, " . ", LastName) Name_Employee, Title Puesto, fn_Age(BirthDate) Edad, fn_Age(HireDate) WorkYears
from employees;`

It returns 24, however if i only consult with select the function it returns 23, the correct answer.

At the moment this is the function i'm using to validate the age is this:

```
create function fn_Age(dateVal date)
returns int
begin
    declare age int;

    if day(now()) and month(now()) >= day(dateVal) and month(dateVal) then
        set age=year(now())-year(dateVal);
    else
        set age=(year(now())-year(dateVal)) - 1;
    end if;

    return age;
end
```

Is there anything i'm not considering in the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)-function

```
select timestampdiff(year, '1994-11-15', now());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
day(now()) and month(now()) >= day(dateVal) and month(dateVal)
```

This logic doesn't make sense.  I don't know if an `if` supports tuples in MySQL.  If so, you can do:

```
(month(now()), date(now())) >= ( month(dateval), day(dateval) )
```

(this works in a MySQL `WHERE` clause.)

You can also do:

```
month(now()) * 100 date(now()) >= month(dateval) * 100 + day(dateval)
```